# Using landmarks in routing directions for ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, routing, network-analyst, navigation

I was wondering if there is a way to use a set of landmarks (in a point class or something) that will be included in the directions output for a Network Analyst route. So if there is a point (or building polygon for that matter) at a corner, the text would read "Turn right at 7-11, on to ***_*____**". I found this thread: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/35424-Displaying-point-features-as-landmarks-on-Network-Analysis-route-direction-maps , but I don't necessarily want to attribute my route paths with building information, which is what I gathered this was doing. I'm using ArcGIS 10. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Landmarks are now a feature of Network Analyst in 10.1

Comment: Can you also utilize this functionality in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript (v. 3.22) using the Directions widget?